# Kubernetes Restart

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, istio

Is it fine to have an application have 1 restart? I tried deploying an application with Istio, but due to some reason after a restart, things are working fine. So is it safe to deploy an application with this status?

Comment: Would be useful to know what's the reason for that restart. Might be some misconfiguration. If you only see 1 restart, it's probably nothing critical, still this should not happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is absolutely fine, and in some cases, it is expected. For example, I have an application that relies on a redis cluster, but the redis cluster takes a while to startup so the application will crash a few times ("unable to connect") until the redis cluster is ready, then the application remains stable.

You should be concerned if the application repeatedly restarts, however, and in that case you should check the logs of the pod to see why that is.